# Setting bufferCommands to false not working in MongooseJs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am using MongooseJs for creating and reading database. I need my Mongoose to display the DB connection errors immediately on requests. but mongoose keeps buffering the connection errors. I also tried setting bufferCommands to false. but no luck...Is there any other method available?

I am using mongoose v5.8.13 and node v10.16.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: When there is a DB connection error, a connection(`error`) event is emitted, you might want to try setting up a listener or this event. More details [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events).

Comment: @OTZ   I also tried connection events. It notifies after 30 seconds of disconnection. I need that notification immediately if my DB connection disconnects

Answer (score 0):

You have to set bufferMaxEntries = 0 as well.

Pass on;
{
bufferMaxEntries:0,
}
as options to mongoose.connect(uri,options) and;

{
bufferCommands:false
}
as options to new Schema(colName,schema,options).

bufferCommands is mongoose specific. Mongodb driver has its own buffering mechanism that has to be disabled by setting bufferMaxEntries:0 and passing this as an option with the connectionstring. This will halt all buffering immediately on a "disconnected" event.

**UPDATE**:Note that {bufferMaxEntries:0} is deprecated and would not work when passing {useUnifiedTopology:true} to the mongodb driver. It looks like UnifiedTopology may not execute buffered operations after a timeout (default is 30 seconds and can be changed with serverSelectionTimeoutMS).

In short, set bufferCommands to false in mongoose schema and set useUnifiedTopology:true and serverSelectionTimeoutMS in mongoose connect to as low as possible. I would suggest 5000ms to catch and respond to failed operations quickly. A lower number may not be optimal. I was unable to establish initial connection with values < 1000ms.